# rust library returned Box object is automatically freed in C -- EDIT: not freed

Tags: c, rust, ffi, address-sanitizer

I have a feeling that ONE rust `Box<Context>` (as `struct Context *` in C) is automatically freed when leaving main.

I have a rust library `/home/codes/libspeakdet.so` from following code in `lib.rs` compiled with `cargo build`

```rust
pub struct Context { pub sim: f32 }

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn make_context() -> Box<Context> {
    Box::new(Context { sim: 0.2733f32 })
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn drop_context(_ctx: Option<Box<Context>>) {}
```

And `test.c` compiled with `cc -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -o test -g test.c /home/codes/libspeakdet.so`

```c
struct Context *make_context();
void drop_context(struct Context *ctx);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct Context *ctx;

    ctx = make_context();
    //drop_context(ctx);
    ctx = make_context();

    return 0;
}
```

with the `drop_context` line commented, running `test` got output

```
==44143==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks
Direct leak of 4 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
...
```

and no leak report with the `drop_context` line uncommented. Having `N` `make_context` calls will have asan report `N-1` objects direct leak.

I'm confused, because I think the `ownership` is a rust feature that frees memory.

How could a C program automatically free that ONE `ctx` when leaving main?

**EDIT**
I think use `Box` to receive C pointer is a example from rust document. [module level document of Box](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/index.html). Please help me understand it if I'm wrong.

> ...
> Here, the struct Foo* type from C is translated to Box, which captures the ownership constraints.
> ...

the document have EXACT code as mine.

**EDIT**
I added these codes just before `return 0` to verify the `still reachable` explain provided by the answers.

```c
    //ctx = NULL;
    ctx = (struct Context *)malloc(7);
    //free(ctx);
```

- setting `ctx = NULL` has no change to the asan report.
- setting `ctx` to malloced 7 bytes made asan report **7** bytes leak.
- after `free` the malloced 7 bytes, asan report became same as without these lines.

EDIT MORE

- parallel experiment

compile the following c code to independent `libleaktest.so`, and link `test.c` to `libleaktest.so` instead, asan reports `N` leaks.

```c
struct Context *make_context() {
    struct Context *ctx = (struct Context *)malloc(9);
    return ctx;
}

void drop_context(struct Context *ctx) {
    free(ctx);
}
```

EDIT MORE

some extra experiment result

valgrind is reporting `N` blocks of `definitely lost` as expected.

When `Context` size is `<=` 460 bytes, the last leak is not reported in asan.

When `Context` size is `>=` 461 bytes, the last leak is reported in asan.

Declare `ctx` as `ctx[1]`, and use `ctx[0]` instead of `ctx` in following code, the last leak is reported in asan (with 4B size Context).

**CONCLUSION**

Thank you for help. I'm pretty sure now, that the `N-1` report behavior is asan bug on rust code. If that block is reachable with 460B size, then it cannot become unreachable with 461B size.

P.S. Fortunately, after commenting each `log4rs` and `println` line, valgrind is quiet and correct again. That was initial reason why I came to use asan instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How could a C program automatically free that ONE `ctx` when leaving main?

It can't, and doesn't, but you're misinterpreting the leak sanitizer.

From the [design doc](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerLeakSanitizerDesignDocument) (with my emphasis):

> The leak checker ... first halts the execution of the process. This ensures that the pointer graph does not change while we examine it, and allows us to collect **any transient pointers from register contexts of running threads**.

> LSan scans this memory for byte patterns that look like pointers to heap blocks ... **Those blocks are considered reachable** and their contents are also treated as live memory. In this manner we discover all blocks reachable from the root set. We then iterate over all existing heap blocks and **report unreachable blocks as leaks**

If the leak sanitizer finds the address of your `Context` in the C variable `ctx`, the object will be considered reachable *and not reported as a leak*.

---

The other way to answer this question

> How could a C program automatically free that ONE `ctx` when leaving main?

is to point out that *everything* is freed when you leave `main`. Program exit reclaims all the program resources (apart from perhaps shared memory and similar cases).

Technically it even reclaims unreachable allocations, because the whole process address space is getting torn down. The reason unreachable allocations are considered leaks is that they could accumulate invisibly during process runtime.

Comment: I didn't see the doc providing a tweak for reporting `still reachable`. Can I pass some parameter to asan for more detailed report?

Comment: If it's still reachable it's considered not a leak by definition. You can verify this by just setting `ctx=NULL` before exiting.

Comment: I've tested with `ctx = NULL` and assigning new value to `ctx`, but the result didn't change. Could you help me? I've edited the question for the test infomation.

Comment: Interesting - I added `printf("%p\n", ctx);` statements for all the `ctx` values, and ran with `LSAN_OPTIONS=report_objects=1`. It's definitely the last allocation which is not detected as a leak, even when I disabled all optimization and confirmed in gdb that I can't see the address anywhere in register or on the stack frame. It's not obvious _where_ the sanitizer is reaching that allocation from, but it definitely is, somehow ...

Comment: Testing of returning raw pointer from rust code was giving same result, and returning raw pointer from C library code DO give `N` leaks. I doubt ownership rule is making some pointer tracked, this could be in consistent with the rule of not reporting reachable memory.

Comment: I disassembled the rust .so and didn't see anything in there that looked like it would store a reachable pointer to the last allocation, so the exact mechanism is a little mysterious, but there's no doubt about your conclusion. Maybe it's some detail of the internal rust allocator.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm confused, because I think the ownership is a rust feature that frees memory.

Yes. The operative word is *Rust* feature. C is not Rust, C does not understand `Box`, C doesn't have `drop`.

Returning Rust objects by value to C is *not correct*. You need to use [`Box::into_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.into_raw) to convert the `Box` to a raw pointer before returning it to C, then you need a freeing function which converts back [`from_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.from_raw) into a `Box` which Rust can drop.

The second operation is obviously wildly unsafe, Rust has no way to verify whether C is lying, so C could provide random garbage or provide the same raw pointer twice, both of which lead to UBs.

> How could a C program automatically free that ONE ctx when leaving main?

It can't. That's just not part of C's semantics.

Comment: Good answer, but it doesn't explain why LeakSanitizer is apparently only detecting N-1 memory leaks when creating N contexts.

Comment: But I think using c pointer to receive Box is suggested by rust document. [module level info of Box](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/index.html) in the `Memory layout` sector.

Comment: I think you missed the bottom of that section that starts with "Even though Box<T> has the same representation and C ABI as a C pointer, this does not mean that you can convert an arbitrary T* into a Box<T> and expect things to work."  That and below that says basically "don't do this"

Comment: No I did not. My pointer WAS come from a valid Box, it's not malloced in C. The last sector in document is a warning saying only pointer from box can be cast to box again.